How to install gdal using conda?
I am trying to run this line: from osgeo import gdal
I am getting this error:
    from osgeo import gdal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'osgeo'

However, I have already installed gdal using conda using the following: conda install -c conda-forge gdal, which is now showing me this: # All requested packages already installed.
If it is already installed, then why is the error still coming?

Check your installed gdal version: conda list, assuming environment is already activated.

Most likely you have another package which is holding back your gdal version to v2. The importing of gdal changed after v3, as reported many times on these forums and elsewhere.

Try:
conda install -c conda-forge osgeo

I'm not that familiar with conda, but I am pretty sure you should be installing the source module and not the submodule.

That is not working either; the same error is occurring and the installation is showing as failed:
`conda install -c conda-forge osgeo



Channels:

conda-forge
defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed`


When using conda it is in general a good idea to avoid mixing packages from different channels.
Anaconda and miniconda use defaults as default channel, so when you use conda install -c conda-forge gdal only gdal will be installed from the conda-forge channel and most other dependencies will be installed from defaults, possibly leading to incompatibilities.
So, when you want to install something explicitly from the conda-forge channel, it is a good idea to create a new environment and configure it so the highest priority is given to conda forge for everything being installed in this environment, like this:
conda create -n gdal_cf
conda activate gdal_cf
conda config --env --add channels conda-forge
conda config --env --set channel_priority strict
conda install gdal

This typically avoids this kind of issues.
Reference: here.
